# I want to select multiple choices by using extended choice parameter and from that choices i want to run job by pasing one sting match

Tags: jenkins, extended-choice-parameter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOjD8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMy1F.png)

As per log  i have selected 3 choices[abc,cdf,mno] and i am matching [abc] and want to execute job or execute shell if choices contains [abc] as a sting. but i am unable to get expected output

```
Run condition [Or] enabling prebuild for step [Execute shell]
[ct_test] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins63839460640800445.sh
+ echo abc,cdf,mno
abc,cdf,mno
Strings match run condition: string 1=[abc,cdf,mno], string 2=[abc]
Strings match run condition: string 1=[abc,cdf,mno], string 2=[mno]
Run condition [Or] preventing perform for step [Execute shell]
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suggest you using list parameter instead of choice selection. I think this will do the trick . First add this to your parameters [image: Choice Parameter Selection]
Then run this pipeline and see if you outputting what you selected

[image: This is the pipeline code]

Comment: This is really good and helpful for pipeline project but i was trying to make this using not jenkins project . I have tried this one and working fine . +1 for giving this concept.

Comment: today i used extended choice parameter and using execute shell for the string match. if someone will find same problem anyone can use thisif [ `echo $test| grep -c "abc" ` -gt 0 ] according to match it will work